# How can I process most jobs in parallel but serialize a subset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, concurrency, architecture, parallel-processing

We get concurrent callbacks to our web application from a vendor and we suspect it's causing us lost updates because they are processed at the same time on different machines.

**We need to serialize the processing of those calls** if and only if they affect the same user record.

A colleague of mine proposed an AWS Kinesis stream where we use the user ID as partition key. The idea is that the same partition key places the record in the same shard. Each shard is processed by only a single worker, and there will be no concurrency issues. By design, it will be guaranteed that records belonging to the same user are not processed in parallel. This solution scales and solves the problem but it will set us back at least a sprint.

**We're trying to find a solution that we can deploy faster.**

Other solutions we have discussed so far:

1. Simply delay the processing of the callbacks, potentially by a random amount of time. In this scenario, it's still possible (though less probable) for several workers to process jobs for the same user at the same time.
2. Any queuing system has the flaw that we are either restricted to one worker or risk parallel processing or the same as outlined in (1).

We are on a Rails stack with MySQL and prefer AWS for our solutions.

**Is there a solution to this problem that will yield faster results than switching to Kinesis?**

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the kind of event that you are getting? It sounds to me that you are getting requests that are mutating the same record, and that the whole record is getting updated at once? Like getting something in line with UPDATE_ADDRESS(user_id, new_address) and UPDATE_PHONE(user_id, new_phone) competing for the user record, and by the time the phone updateis done, it overwritten the new address with the old one. Or do we have another scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You basically are looking for named distributed locks, so that you can enforce serial processing.

If you are in AWS, you could push a record to DynamoDB with each customerId.

Each time you get a record for processing, do a consistent read (see the concurrency section here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/APISummary.html).

If a record is present, add your message to it (consistent write).  Have the process that is processing do a read after it's done, and if there are messages appended to the dynamo record, process them serially.  Finally delete the record.

It is possible you will get race conditions, so you will need to do a back-off and retry.  I don't know what your volume is, but Dynamo is pretty fast, so the odds of hitting this more than a couple of times is slim.  If it fails too many times, you might have to dump things to an error queue for cleaning up, but it's pretty unlikely.  Especially if your volume allows for you to consider solutions like arbitrary delay in message processing.

Answer (score 0):

Only some theoretical input:

If you have callbacks that are technically independent you need an semantic identifier that marks them as dependent or independent and an sequence id that ensures the execution order. The user ID is not sufficient. How can you ensure the proper database execution order of parallel web requests of one user?

If you have unique transaction ids you can apply isolation levels like serialization. But in this case you are not invulnerable against "your" lost updates either. They will also happen when you use serialization unless you don't have a sequence number (version) and a locking mechanism.

Be sure you talk about "overwriting uncommitted data" if you mean "lost updates" to avoid missunderstandings. This will be handled with at least isolation level "repeatable read".

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that in your callbacks request, you have a field that determines the ordering of those callbacks for a particular user. Otherwise, there is no meaning of serialization. You can store the mapping of order UserId last callback's orderId.
Now whenever you are processing a task you just check the last orderId for that user and if the task is not the next desired callback you put it back into the queue. your system will fully run in parallel and consistency will also be maintained.

You can user celery for running tasks and rabbitmq for queuing.